# Material UI Color Palette get hex code of auto generated shades

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to use different shades of my defined colors within my material ui theme. I define only the main color:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: "#C5FFA1",
        },
```

For some use cases I need the hex value of other sades of the main color. How can I transform the `rgb(...)` value the auto generated `primary.dark` variable returns into hex code? I couldn't find any solution.

```
import { useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
const theme = useTheme();
console.log(theme.palette.primary.main);
console.log(theme.palette.primary.dark);
```

returns this

```
#D6F0FF
rgb(149, 168, 178)
```

yet I need this:

```
#D6F0FF
#95a8b2
```

Answer (score 1):

import { rgbToHex } from "@material-ui/core";

const hex = rgbToHex("rgb(149, 168, 178)")

// There's a bunch of util functions in @material-ui/core, like rgbToHex

// full list here: https://unpkg.com/browse/@material-ui/core@3.1.1/es/styles/colorManipulator.d.ts

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of primary.main try setting only primary as

```
primary:"#C5FFA1"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this throws the error `Error: Material-UI: The color provided to augmentColor(color) is invalid.
The color object needs to have a `main` property or a `500` property.`

Comment: This works for me `let theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#006a4d",
      dark: "#006a4f"
    },
    secondary: amber,
  },
})`

Comment: Thank you for your reploy, but in this example you set the dark color explicitly. Material-UI also creates the dark/light colors [automatically](https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/#providing-the-colors-directly). My question is how I can get the hex color codes of these automatic colors.

Comment: I think that feature is not provided by material-ui. you need to specify all the color variations that you want to use in your application